# Best way to connect PCB to enclosed AC/DC power supply

Tags: interconnect, wire-terminals

I'm trying to minimize assembly time in a system that will require a PCB interfaced to an enclosed AC/DC power supply.  Unfortunately, on-board AC/DC converters are not economical for my power requirements (10A @ 12VDC). I'd love to avoid crimping spade terminals to the hundreds of wires (45 systems with one power supply each, 7 terminals per power supply).

Here are some options that I'm considering:

- Integrated PCB spade terminals - I saw this design on the X-Carve website--seems like it should work, maybe I'd gold plate the fingers to be safe?  I'd probably design it to be a spade terminal instead of ring terminal to cut down on assembly time.  I haven't seen this design elsewhere--any reason this is a bad idea?

[image: X Carve Power Supply Interface]

- Repurposing a terminal lug like 7236 from Keystone.  I'd need to bend the terminal lugs or orient the PCB perpendicular to the power supply.

[image: 7236 from Keystone]

Any other ideas out there?

Comment: Box Build is a standard contract manufacturer service world wide, I assume you have quoted the price difference between a box build and the effort and cost of developing and producing a bespoke PCB?

Comment: Have you worked out how long it will take you to crimp 315 wires onto spade terminals, when compared with designing a reliable alternative?  I suspect the crimping option may be quicker.

Comment: @SimonB finishing  hundreds of crimps to meet a deadline  is what is sometimes known in the business as  "an exciting weekend".

Answer (score 1):

When you have a heavy assembly like the PSU you propose, there is an important consideration with wire connections: vibration. The wire harness to the PSU provides isolation between and the rest of your system so that they don't couple.

Your spade-lug proposal defeats that purpose as it makes a direct mechanical connection between the two. Shock and vibe testing will lead to broken terminals and cracked PCBs. You don't want that.

Instead, I would look at a couple of options:

- Use wire-to-board connections (e.g, Molex Mini-Fit or similar) between the PSU and your system
- Use the crimped spade-lug approach, and outsource the harness-building

The latter approach takes advantage of the equipment the outsource vendor will have on hand, which will not only reduce labor cost but improve repeatability (always an issue with crimp terminals.)

Comment: thanks for the response--the board I'm interfacing will be a very small adapter board with minimal mass--I don't believe that vibration will be a significant problem, especially for this static system (which will have vibration absorbing feet).

Comment: Shock and vibe testing is not just about how the system performs when it's installed, but also when it ships. It includes drop testing as well as 3 axes of vibration at various frequencies. Your proposal will not do well in this testing, despite your assumption about the weight of your sub-board.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, as you may well know, these types of enclosed supplies are used in a "box".

> [image]
>
> Courtesy of https://www.fourstarconnections.com/ (no affiliation)

So wire terminations are used and PCB's are connected to a wire harness, bus, or backplane of some kind.

The challenge I see with the approach in your photos, which I agree is clever, is the significant amount of bend and other stress that will be put on the substrate (PCB) when used without additional strain relief or stand-off.

Comment: It also allows replacing the PSU with a model that has a different connector layout, only the wiring position needs to be changed (not an entire PCB).

Comment: @David very true, an additional point, if you use the device according to the mfg specification using industry standard wiring practices, you can rely to some degree on the device rating for UL and CE defenses. By making a custom part to effectively modify another part, you are now taking on that safety risk for yourself and may have a harder time passing certification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea because of what FR4 is made of. Most PCB substrates are made with resin and fiberglass. Under pressure and over time, the resin creeps out under your terminals, loosening the contact and/or breaking and creating issues where you would want maximum reliability.

Comment: Heat accelerates this too, which may be a concern if the power supply isn't particularly efficient.